# How to make a makefile that will compile C, C++, and Java files all at once

Tags: java, c++, c, makefile

I'm trying to create a Makefile that will compile and run 3 different implementations of a markov algorithm all at once. I'm new to makefiles so if there's multiple mistakes, please let me know. Also, if I wanted to optimize the compiles with -O3, where would I do that?

When I run, I currently get these errors:

> Makefile:28: warning: overriding commands for target `markov.o'
>
> Makefile:22: warning: ignoring old commands for target `markov.o'
>
> make: *** No rule to make target `Markov.java', needed by`java_markov.class'.  Stop.

Here is the code for my makefile:

```
javaC=javac
javaR=java
CC=g++
CC=gcc

CFLAGS=-O0
OPT=-deprecation
TARGET1=./java_markov
TARGET2=./markov_cpp
TARGET3=./markov_c
INFILE=./alice30.txt
OUTFILE1=./markov_java_out.txt
OUTFILE2=./output/markov_cpp_out.txt
OUTFILE3=./output/markov_c_out.txt

$(TARGET1).class: Markov.java
    $(javaC) Markov.java

$(TARGET2): markov.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET2) markov.o
markov.o: markov.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c markov.cpp


$(TARGET3) : markov.o eprintf.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET3) markov.o eprintf.o
markov.o : markov.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c markov.c
eprintf.o : eprintf.c eprintf.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c eprintf.c

clean:
    rm -f *.class $(OUTFILE1)
    rm -f *.o $(TARGET2) $(OUTFILE2)
    rm -f *.o $(TARGET3) $(OUTFILE3)
run: $(TARGET1).class
    $(javaR) $(TARGET1) < $(INFILE) > $(OUTFILE1)
    $(TARGET2)
    $(TARGET2) <$(INFILE) >$(OUTFILE2)
    $(TARGET3)
    $(TARGET3) < $(INFILE) > $(OUTFILE3)
```

Comment: 4th line, you set CC to gcc (GNU compiler collection) after setting it to g++.  On my computer using gcc on a .cpp file doesn't work as it ends up running the C compiler.  Try using one variable for gcc on .c sources, and another for g++ on .cpp sources

Comment: Why does this have to be a make file? Do a make file for the C and C++ versions, then do your running in a shell or python script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You *do* have two rules to make `markov.o`. Try renaming one of them, if you really have C and C++ ports in the same folder: e.g.

  ```
  markov-c++.o: markov.cpp
  $(TARGET2): markov-c++.o …
  ```
- You really don't *have* to use 2-step compilation with an intermediate `.o` file, if you're not linking in any more `.o`'s. You could just do

  ```
  $(TARGET2): markov.cpp
      $(CC) $(CFLAGS) markov.cpp -o $(TARGET2)
  ```
- The other warning indicates that there's no file named `Markov.java` in the directory. Is it perhaps in a subdirectory or something?
- `make run` is pretty broken :-) I think you just wanted to put all three targets on the prerequisites line?